# How to move a file in git after the fact?

Tags: git

I got that situation where in a clone of a branch I have messed with a file, renamed it, moved it to different locations, even had 2 copies of it (don't ask...) and now I have finally decided for the final location.

However, whenever I merge changes in that file git recreates the file in the old location (with the old name) instead of merging it with the new file.

How can I tell git to consider the new file as move of the old one?

**Update**

I tried to solve it myself by doing these steps:

1. Move new file back to old location and rename it back.
2. Commit and push.
3. Merge original branch to the clone with changes in that file.
4. Move and rename file back to what it was.
5. Commit and push.

Then I made another change in the original branch and merged again only to see git creating the old file again.

Comment: Is that possible to 1) stash the current situation; 2) checkout this file from the branch you want to merge, 3) move this specific version of file into the target direction; 4) conduct the merge; 5) unstash and merge again? I suppose step 5 can be done without actual merge, so you can just commit --amend.

Answer (score 0):

If the git automatic merging doesn't do what you want, you should do manual merging:

1. `git merge <branch> --no-commit --no-ff`

   This starts the merge at the branch
2. Fix all the files manually.

   All the actions you did for the repo confused git and by defining the correct state directly into the merge commit, you save the trouble for later.
3. `git add` and `git commit`

   Commit your changes.

Comment: I don't know what to do with your second point. What should I exactly fix?